# codeigniter and jquery uploadify

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have using codeigniter and jquery uploadify for my image gallery. It works fine in my localhost. My problem is when I uploaded into the server.

Any help would highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

the error is:

```
'Data Loaded: <p>The path to the image is not correct.</p><p>Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image.</p>'
```

root of my project is (codeiguploadify)

here is the link
http://webberzsoft.com/clients/codeiguploadify/

I already tried to change my folder into 'folder' : 'clients/codeiguploadify/uploads', but still doestn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fileInput2").uploadify({
        'uploader'       : 'flash/uploadify.swf',
        'script'         : 'uploadify/uploadify.php',
        'cancelImg'      : 'flash/cancel.png',
        'folder'         : 'uploads',
        'multi'          : true     
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error

```
Your server does not support the GD function required to process this type of image
```

I would say your localhost has the required GD library package, and your other server has not. Can you double check PHP has access to GD

You can use the following PHP code to check this ([taken from here](http://www.dagondesign.com/files/gd-test.txt)):

```
<?php
/* Displays details of GD support on your server */
echo '<div style="margin: 10px;">';
echo '<p style="color: #444444; font-size: 130%;">GD is ';
if (function_exists("gd_info")) {
    echo '<span style="color: #00AA00; font-weight: bold;">supported</span> by your server!</p>';
    $gd = gd_info();
    foreach ($gd as $k => $v) {
        echo '<div style="width: 340px; border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD; padding: 2px;">';
        echo '<span style="float: left;width: 300px;">' . $k . '</span> ';
        if ($v)
            echo '<span style="color: #00AA00; font-weight: bold;">Yes</span>';
        else
            echo '<span style="color: #EE0000; font-weight: bold;">No</span>';
        echo '<div style="clear:both;"><!-- --></div></div>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<span style="color: #EE0000; font-weight: bold;">not supported</span> by your server!</p>';
}
echo '<p>by <a href="http://www.dagondesign.com">dagondesign.com</a></p>';
echo '</div>';
?>
```